# How to solve an differential equation system?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I want to reproduce some waveforms to get general info about the system, I've been attempting with some ODE solvers from Matlab as `ode45`, `ode15i`, `ode15s`, `ode23`, and also I try to get the waveforms with simulink using `Ode1` (euler method) and `ode4` (runge-kutta method) but I cant reproduce it, I suppose that I need only a little setting in the parameters or in the integration interval.

this is my code:

```
clear all
clc
close all

%// System constants 
a=(5400*10^-3);
b=30;
%// z=0;
z=0.008;
%// z=-0.023;
%// z=0.034;

c=0.00017;
d=0.001;
e=0.01;
h=0.1;

q=0.024;
r=0.088;
s=0.046;

f=@(t,x)[-a*(((c*x(1)^3)+(d*x(1)^2)+(e*x(1))+h)-x(2)-z);b*(((c*x(1)^3)+         (d*x(1)^2)+(e*x(1))+h)-q*exp(r*x(1))+s-x(2))];

tspan=[-550 600];
x0=[0 0];


[X,Y]=ode45(f,(tspan),[0.0432,0]);

figure
plot(Y)
figure
plot(Y(:,1),Y(:,2),'-')
```

[image: It is not what I'm looking]

Comment: Just for you to know, In those nice figures you ploted, there is a save icon. the save icon can save the figures as .png and other formats withou t needeg a screeshot of your computer

Comment: Using MATLAB R2010b on Windows 10 is a bit awkward. Lots of possible answers will involve functions that are introduced in 2011 or later, since the ode solver of MATLAB underwent quite the make-over.

Comment: "but I cant reproduce it" ... Can't reproduce what?  Without a differential equation/block diagram, I can't see what's wrong since the program runs just fine.  Also, the posted code does not generate the plots in the image (while I am using R2014b, I can't imagine `ode45` has changed that much).

Comment: @TroyHaskin Sorry I can't add more images, but I want to reproduce the fig.2 b
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vgqpaiu2hw7e3k/2015-10-18%2020.49.55.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @Adriaan I take in account your comment, I'll looking for another version as son as posible. Thanks